# Is there a name in Haskell for `[m a] -> m a`?

Tags: haskell, monads, traversable

Let's say I have a `Future` monad, so `Future a` represents an `a` that may or may not yet be available. Then `sequenceA` automatically gives me the semantics "wait for all of these futures to be ready and give me all their values":

```hs
sequenceA :: [Future a] -> Future [a]
```

This is something like a logical AND, since it doesn't become ready until all the inputs are ready. Carrying that metaphor further, we could define the logical OR: "become ready with the value of the first input that becomes ready".

```hs
firstReady: [Future a] -> Future a
```

Does this metaphore generalize to other monads/traversables? Is there a standard name for this operation?

Comment: Similar to https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.2.4/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:waitAny

Comment: Not in a generic form of `Monad m` no, but can be specific for `Future`.

Comment: Isn't this msum/asum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `async` package exposes the [`Concurrently`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.2.4/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#t:Concurrently) newtype which has an `Alternative` instance that gives rise to the "return the first thing that finishes" behavior.

The `firstReady` function is called `asum :: [Concurrently a] -> Concurrently a`.

But note that `Concurrently` doesn't have a monad instance, because it wouldn't be possible to satisfy the law:

```
m1 <*> m2 = m1 >>= (\x1 -> m2 >>= (\x2 -> return (x1 x2)))
```

(The `<*>` runs both its arguments at the same time but the `>>=` is forced to run its first argument fully before it can start running its second argument.)